# Ext2 block structure: size of reserved GDT Blocks

Tags: filesystems, ext2, superblock

In every publication I found about ext2, the structure of a block group is defined as following:

- Super Block: 1 block
- Group Descriptor: N blocks
- Data Bitmap: 1 block
- Inode Bitmap: 1 block
- Inode Table: N blocks
- Data Blocks: remaining blocks

However in the [ext2 kernel doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext2.txt) it is stated that versions >0 may not store copies of the super block and group descriptors in every block group.

When I `fsstat` my ext2 partition, I get following output:

```
Group: 1:
  Inode Range: 1977 - 3952
  Block Range: 8193 - 16384
  Layout:
    Super Block: 8193 - 8193
    Group Descriptor Table: 8194 - 8194
    Data bitmap: 8451 - 8451
    Inode bitmap: 8452 - 8452
    Inode Table: 8453 - 8699
    Data Blocks: 8700 - 16384
  Free Inodes: 1976 (100%)
  Free Blocks: 0 (0%)
  Total Directories: 0

Group: 2:
  Inode Range: 3953 - 5928
  Block Range: 16385 - 24576
  Layout:
    Data bitmap: 16385 - 16385
    Inode bitmap: 16386 - 16386
    Inode Table: 16387 - 16633
    Data Blocks: 16387 - 16386, 16634 - 24576
  Free Inodes: 1976 (100%)
  Free Blocks: 0 (0%)
```

There are two things about this output that confuse me:

1. In groups where the SB and group desc. are stored, there is a gap of 256 blocks between the group desc. and data bitmap. 
   **EDIT: Using `dumpe2fs` I just found out that these are reserved GDT blocks, [used for online resizing](https://www.redhat.com/archives/ext3-users/2006-May/msg00008.html).**
   So the new question is, how is the size of these reserved GDT blocks determined?
2. What does `Data Blocks: 16387 - 16386` in Group 2 mean?

Comment: It looks like this program is simply buggy.  How large of a filesystem is this?

Comment: It's a 100 MB file mounted as ext2 partition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resize_inode feature creates a hidden inode (number 7, you can view it in `debugfs` with `stat <7>`) to reserve those blocks so that the GDT can be grown. By default it reserves enough space to grow the filesystem to 1024 times its original size. You can disable the feature or adjust the size using options to `mke2fs` at format time.

> What does Data Blocks: 16387 - 16386 in Group 2 mean?

This looks to simply be a bug in the program, as you can't have a negative-sized (ends before it starts) range.

Comment: OK, but why is the size 256 then?

Comment: @goose999, because that is 1024 times the size of the group descriptor table.

Comment: `gdt_blocks = (sizeof(struct ext2_group_desc) * number_of_groups) / block_size` for 100MB partition, 1kb blocksize `gdt_blocks = (32 * 12.5) / 1024 = 0.39 ~ 1 block` so the formula for reserved GDT blocks should be `res_gdt_blocks = 32 * 12.5 = 400`. What is wrong in my calculation?

Comment: @goose999, you should only have 4 block groups, so 4 * 32 = 128 bytes, so 1024 times that is 128 blocks.

Comment: @psusis the ext2 doc states `max_bg_size = 8 * blocksize` therefore `bg_count = 102400 / (8*1024) = 12.5` should be correct

Comment: @goose999, ahh, I forgot about that silly arbitrary limitation on the smaller block sizes.  In that case, it should be 13 ( you can only have a whole number of block groups ) * 32 = 416 blocks.

Comment: So the big question is again why there are 256 blocks reserved? However I found out that I can also extract the number of reserved GDT blocks from the suberblock via sb->s_padding1

Comment: @goose999, I checked the source and it seems that the number of reserved blocks is capped at how many will fit in a single indirect block, which for 1k block size is 256.  I guess they didn't want to be bothered with having to allocate more than a single indirect block.

Comment: To limit the number of *reserved GDT blocks*, specify `mke2fs -E resize=...` with the smallest value it allows.

Comment: To get rid of *reserved GDT blocks* completely, specify `mke2fs -O ^resize_inode`.